# Running Chrome and IE tests in parallel in same node

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

What are the issues occur due to running IE and Chrome/Firefox browsers tests in parallel in the same node.

As nativeEvents, requireWindowFocus, enablePersistentHover are enabled for IE, will it cause impact on tests running in chrome/firefox.

If there is any issue due to the caps, will this be avoided with any grid configurations like grid-extras?

Comment: What happens when you try doing it ? Can you please call out the set of issues that you have encountered ? IMO that would be a bit more apt question to ask, by sharing your experience.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan,  We are facing issues when related to mouse over events we have enabled nativeEvents which is causing tests to fail. So we ceased to test both the browsers in same node parallel. I have asked this question after facing that, issue, so seeking some help from someone who have faced issues, as we can't have all the permutations done and tested.